# How to get Euler–Mascheroni's constant in R?

Tags: r

Is [Euler–Mascheroni's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma \approx 0.577$ available in R, similarly to $\pi$ with `pi` or $e$ with `exp(1)`?

Comment: deleted ... that was my bad ... thanks for noticing @Dason

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mathmatically we can write the constant of interest as the negative of the derivative of the gamma function evaluated at 1.  R has the derivative of the gamma function as `digamma` so it's just a matter of plugging this in.

```
-digamma(1)
#[1] 0.5772157
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
eulergamma = 0.57721566490153 # just copy from e.g. wiki to whatever precision you need it
```

Now use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(-digamma(1), digits=22 )
```